# Upper bounds for the number of roots of polynomials, over finite fields, lying in given extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, finite-fields, analytic-number-theory

Let $F$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, where $q$ is a power of a prime, and let $E$ be its degree $n \geq 2$ extension. Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(E) = F$. Clearly the number of distinct roots of $f(x)$ which lie in $E$ is at most $\deg(f(x))$.

In the special case when many of the monomials of $f(x)$ are of the form $x^{qk}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, say including the leading monomial, can we give a better general upper bound for the number of distinct roots of $f(x)$ in $E$? Thanks.

Comment: The condition $f(E)=F$ is strange, are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes, surjective onto $F$, but I am not sure this is that relevant here.

Comment: I assume $q$ is prime?  So if all your monomials are of that form then $f(x)=(g(x))^q$ and so the number of distinct roots would have to be at most deg$(f)/q$.  Does that make sense or am I saying something stupid?

Comment: It does. $q$ could be a prime power here. In my case, not all monomials are of that form. Nevertheless the vast majority of them are.

Comment: It's hard to see how to say anything if any of the monomials are not of that form.  But I'm still thinking.

Comment: For example $f(x)=x^q+x$, i.e. the relative trace, is of that form, and has exactly $q$ zeros. I don't know what kind of a result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is also the case with the trace function $T$ itself. Because the derivative of $x$, which is that of $T$ and your $f$, is coprime to both $T, f$ and hence $T, f$ have no repeated roots. In general these kind of polynomials can be written as $f(x) = g(x) + (h(x))^q$, where the exponent of the monomials of $g(x)$ are coprime to $q$, say they are all $1 \pmod{q}$. Thus $f'(x) = g'(x) $ and all the exponents of $g'(x)$ have become divisible by $q$.  I wonder what else could be added here that could be of use...